# Declaring String constants

Tags: string, c++11, constants

What's the advantage of declaring:

```
static constexpr const char* K = "k";
```

versus:

```
static const std::string K("k");
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, the first one is obviously a compile-time constant expression, while the second one allocates dynamic memory at run-time. It all depends on your use case.

Comment: So there is no definitive advantage of the first form ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference, how it will affect your code depends on many things. Generally the second is not recommended due to the fact that you can not guarantee when the std::string object will be constructed or destructed.

It is best summed up by the [Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Static_and_Global_Variables):

> Variables of class type with static storage duration are forbidden: they cause hard-to-find bugs due to indeterminate order of construction and destruction. However, such variables are allowed if they are constexpr: they have no dynamic initialization or destruction.
>
> Objects with static storage duration, including global variables, static variables, static class member variables, and function static variables, must be Plain Old Data (POD): only ints, chars, floats, or pointers, or arrays/structs of POD.

They forbid the second:

> As a result we only allow static variables to contain POD data. This rule completely disallows std::vector (use C arrays instead), or string (use const char []).

Comment: Note that Google isn't seen as an authority on C++. For instance, to suggest C arrays as alternative to `std::vector` is completely ignoring `std::array`.